# Restricting Access to Rails App based on IP-Address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, network-programming

I want to make an application that will be accessible only from a specific network connection. More clearly, it will be a attendance application. Users can only check in from a specific network connection. If they are connected with other network, they can not able to check in.
How can I do it in Ruby on Rails. Please give me some idea. Actually I need to know that how to detect a specific network connection?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `ApplicationController` add this:

```
before_filter :block_foreign_hosts

def whitelisted?(ip)
  return true if [123.43.65.1, 123.43.65.77].include?(ip)
  false
end

def block_foreign_hosts
  return false if whitelisted?(request.remote_ip)
  redirect_to "https://www.google.com" unless request.remote_ip.start_with?("123.456.789")
end
```

Of cause you have to replace the IP-Network I used in this example with the one you want to have access.

Comment: Hi davidb, thanks for your answer. It solved my problem. Now one more thing. If I want to make a white list of IP addresses which I want to allow then what can i do?

Comment: I added whitelisting to my code of cause you have to replace `[123.43.65.1, 123.43.65.77]` with your whitelist array.

Comment: Thank you so much. :D I can store white listed IP in the database and check it in to the whitelisted?(ip) method. am I right?